# Problem after first cocoapod installation

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

So this is the problem I'm having. Initially after the first one or two cocoapods install/updates everything was working fine. Then on subsequent updates I started getting duplicate dependency files which makes the build fail and screws with live preview in swiftui. There may be other issues but this seems to be the main one from my point of view(though let me know if you think there are other issues). I have included a screenshot of the pertinent errors
[image]

These are the pods I'm currently using:
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'

This is very frustrating as I cannot continue to work on the project until this is resolves and it continues to happen. I tried doing pod deintegrate, deleting podfiles, podfile.lock and the xcworkspace and then re-installing with pod init and pod install but that didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

Would try these steps first.

clean the project

delete derived data

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

"Then on subsequent updates I started getting duplicate dependency files which makes the build fail"

- If you're seeing issues when updating a pod, then you may want to set the pod to a specified version in your Podfile.

Comment: Should I clean the project in the xcworkspace or xcodeproj file? Or does it even matter?